# Using git to grep through a file's previous versions?

Tags: git

Is there a command that would allow me to check if the string `"xyz"` was ever in file `foo.c` in the repository and print which revisions they were found in?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This will print any commits where the diff contains `xyz`

```
git log -Sxyz foo.c
```

Same thing but more readable:

```
git log -S "xyz" foo.c
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555410/is-it-possible-to-search-through-git-stash-items for the equivalent search through the stash. This might help, for example, if you stashed something instead of commiting it.

Comment: For me this is only searching in the logs but not in the content

Answer (score 10):

This will print any commits where the diff contains xyz.  Note the `--` separating the filename from the rest of the command.

```
git log -Sxyz -- foo.c
```

Without the `--`, I get this error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'foo.c': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I originally wanted to comment on [CaptainPicard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/89008/9020923) to add a correction, but I don't have sufficient reputation yet.  If someone would like to edit that answer to mention this correction I'll be happy to take this answer down.

Comment: (currently) git only seems to require the `--` when the file does not exist in the current directory. So it seems both answers are correct.

Comment: @Nwyfiant, you are stuck, like me, with "99" karma. Can't seem to pass from this number! I will give you +1 now :)