# Is it possible to search through Git stash items?

Tags: git

So I'm learning about using Git stash this week and figured out all of these stashes have been accumulating on my system. I've misplaced some code and I now have a dozen stashes of code 0-11.

Is there a way that I can search through these stashes for a string value in the files within the stash to find the code I'm looking for?
Or do I just have to go through and reapply each stash to search/look in them for the code I'm trying to find?

---

**2021/03/18:** I have found other information that sort of relates.

You can create a Git alias to search all your stashes. Modify your `.gitconfig` file and call `git stash-search <pattern>`.

```ini
[alias]
    stash-search = "!f() { git show $(git stash list | cut -d\":\" -f 1) | grep \"$@\" ; }; f"
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`git stash show -p stash@{n} | grep "john cena"` is the only option I think.

Of course you can write your own script around that.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/libinvarghese/e899fb4f6978734f1910b7ead6d6bc06 This would help you search in all stash

Comment: @LibinVarghese, oneliner: `git show $(git stash list | cut -d":" -f 1) | grep "john cena"`

Comment: Note that `git show` of a stash hash-or-name is very different from `git stash show` of a stash hash-or-name. This is because each `stash@{n}` refers to a commit that's not a sensible merge, but `git show` thinks it *is*, and shows it wrong.

Comment: Also, be aware that it's possible to give a name to stash. In this case you need to refer by it's name, rather than default stash@{n}.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question which was about `items`, not single `item`. A comment with `cut` does it right, but the answer from Joshua (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57601163/1416144) with alias using `for` is much better - has also tracking of stash number.

Answer (score 48):

There are some helpful ideas [in this Gist and discussion thread](https://gist.github.com/hartym/2584767).

First, just listing matching stashes is easy (with or without `-i`, depending if case matters)

```bash
git stash list -i -G<regexp>
```

If there's not that much to dig through, you can just add `-p` to print the matching stashes in their entirety.

```bash
git stash list -i -p -G<regexp>
```

With more power for "real" cases, add it to `.gitconfig`:

```ini
[alias]
    stashgrep = "!f() { for i in `git stash list --format=\"%gd\"` ; \
              do git stash show -p $i | grep -H --label=\"$i\" \"$@\" ; done ; }; f"
```

and then you can call `git stashgrep` with any grep arguments you like (`-w`, `-i`).  e.g.,

```bash
git stashgrep -i <regexp>
```

This differs from some answers above, in that it prepends the stash ID to show you where each difference came from:

```
% git stashgrep -i tooltip
stash@{5}: //            resetBatchActionTooltip();
stash@{5}:         addAcceleratorsAndTooltips(lToolMenu, lToolButton, iListener, iTool);
stash@{5}:     private void addAcceleratorsAndTooltips(AbstractButton lToolMenu,
stash@{5}:+        String lToolTip = iTool.getToolTipText();
stash@{5}:             lToolButton.setToolTipText(lToolTip);
stash@{20}:+    private static final String invalidSelectionTooltip = "Invalid selection.  Please choose another.";
stash@{20}:-    private final String invalidSelectionTooltip = "Invalid selection.  Please choose another.";
stash@{20}:                         ((JTextField)lComponent).setToolTipText(
```

Comment: For me, this is better than the accepted answer, because it gives the stash ID. The accepted answer isn't much use to me if I don't know which stash the results are from.

Comment: You can do this if you are familiar with VI:
`git stash list -i -p |less`

Comment: @MartinP., I like your idea, perhaps worth an answer.  (Maybe a little heavy with large stashes, searching back to the header, but very quick and easy.)  How does the -i change the behavior?

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg you are right -i is not needed. I had 25 stash and "less" works fine.

Answer (score 19):

`git stash list -S "my string"` works on Git 2.28 to find patches that add or remove `"my string"`.

I don't know how long this capability has been around; the documentation implies that it should accept all the same options as `git log`, including `-S`, but I distinctly remember not being able to search this way a few years ago.

Answer (score 7):

One-liner:

```
git grep whatever $(git stash list -q | cut -d":" -f 1)
```

and git grep conveniently outputs the the changed line with the name of the stash and the name of the file:

```
stash@{43}:common/ot/whatever.js:exports.whatever = (foo, deps) => {
stash@{44}:common/ot/whatever.js:exports.whatever = (foo, deps) => {
```

Comment: This doesn't search the changed code in the stashes.  It searches the entire resulting work-tree, including files that did not change in the stashed commit.  (So if I search for "whatever" in my stashes in this way, every stash shows up with the same matching lines from the same long-untouched files)

Answer (score 4):

The `git grep` command accepts a "tree" object:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> git grep [-a | --text] [-I] [--textconv] [-i | --ignore-case] [-w | --word-regexp]
>               [-v | --invert-match] [-h|-H] [--full-name]
>               [-E | --extended-regexp] [-G | --basic-regexp]
>               [-P | --perl-regexp]
>               [-F | --fixed-strings] [-n | --line-number]
>               [-l | --files-with-matches] [-L | --files-without-match]
>               [(-O | --open-files-in-pager) [<pager>]]
>               [-z | --null]
>               [-c | --count] [--all-match] [-q | --quiet]
>               [--max-depth <depth>]
>               [--color[=<when>] | --no-color]
>               [--break] [--heading] [-p | --show-function]
>               [-A <post-context>] [-B <pre-context>] [-C <context>]
>               [-W | --function-context]
>               [--threads <num>]
>               [-f <file>] [-e] <pattern>
>               [--and|--or|--not|(|)|-e <pattern>...]
>               [ [--[no-]exclude-standard] [--cached | --no-index | --untracked] | <tree>...]
>               [--] [<pathspec>...]
> ```

Now consider that a stash entry is a tree object synthesized from the
contents of the work tree at the time you have called `git stash`
with its two parents being the state at `HEAD`
and the state in the index; to cite the manual:

> A stash is represented as a commit whose tree records
>   the state of the working
>   directory, and its first parent is the commit at `HEAD`
>   when the stash was created.
>   The tree of the second parent records the state of the index when the
>   stash is made, and it is made a child of the `HEAD` commit.
>   The ancestry graph looks like this:
>
> ```
>               .----W
>              /    /
>        -----H----I
> ```
>
> where `H` is the `HEAD` commit,
>   `I` is a commit that records the state of the index,
>   and `W` is a commit that records the state of the working tree.

So you can have tree places to grep your stash entry for:

- `git grep [options] term stash@{n}` would grep that `W` commit
  for the `term`, that is,
  it would grep the saved state of the working tree files.
- To grep the state of the index of a stashed entry you need to refer
  to the second parent of `W`; this is done using the `^2` suffix:

  ```
   git grep [options] term stash@{n}^2
  ```
- To grep the state of the stash entry's baseline commit—the least
  interesting case—refer to its first parent:

  ```
   git grep [options] term stash@{n}^1
  ```

The `^<n>` notation is explained in the `git help revisions` manual:

> `<rev>^`, e.g. `HEAD^`, `v1.5.1^0` A suffix `^` to a revision
>   parameter means the first parent of that commit object.  `^<n>` means
>   the `<n>`th parent (i.e. `<rev>^` is equivalent to `<rev>^1`). As a
>   special rule, `<rev>^0` means the commit itself and is used when
>   `<rev>` is the object name of a tag object that refers to a commit
>   object.

#### TL;DR

For the top stash entry, use

- `git grep whatever stash@{0}` to grep what was the state of the
  working tree.
- `git grep whatever stash@{0}^2` to grep what was the state of the
  index.

Comment: @Elijah, it helps to understand that stash entries--while "special" in some ways--are just true merge commits in all other ways, and you can do with them whatever you'd do with any other commit.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the popular answers I use this:

```
git stash list -p |less
```

I think it's easier to remember.

Answer (score 0):

To add to 
Andrejs Cainikovs answer you can add seq to search through all of it
`seq 0 5 | xargs -I {} git stash show -p stash@{\{\}}  | grep your_pattern`