# Git stash list with pathspec

Tags: git, git-stash

[The documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-listltoptionsgt) for `git stash list` says

> The command takes options applicable to the `git log` command to control what is shown and how. See [`git-log`[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

If I run an ordinary `git stash list`, it shows me a list of `stash@{N}`, with lots of "WIP on branch1," "WIP on branch2," and so on.

But if I try `git stash list -- doc` to look for stashes specifically affecting documentation, it does *this...*

```
HEAD@{33}: checkout: moving from master to abcdef123
HEAD@{46}: checkout: moving from branch1 to master
HEAD@{67}: pull: Fast-forward
HEAD@{68}: checkout: moving from branch1 to master
HEAD@{71}: pull: Fast-forward
HEAD@{74}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/branch2
HEAD@{75}: rebase: WIP
HEAD@{76}: rebase: WIP
HEAD@{77}: rebase: Docs: New feature explanation (This is a commit message)
HEAD@{78}: rebase: checkout branch3
HEAD@{79}: checkout: moving from branch1 to branch3
HEAD@{81}: rebase: updating HEAD
...
```

What *is* that!? And how do I see stashes filtered to a certain pathspec?

#### Update 2022-10-04

Now you get no list at all, just

```
fatal: bad revision 'doc'
```

Comment: That looks like a bug. Try `git log -g --oneline refs/stash -- doc` to see if that helps. (I feel like I've answered this one before, I'm pretty sure I've looked at this exact bug before.)

Comment: @torek If you find the dup at some point, please feel free to link it.

Comment: This is hacky and I've wished stash list would respect the pathspec intuitively, _but_: `stash show -p` prints the path and filename, so you could find stashes affecting a file by just grepping the patches. e.g,. see [this command for finding stashes matching a pattern anywhere in the diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57601163/411282).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

You can't pass a pathspec to the listing variant of the `git stash` command itself, but you *can* get the list of stashes filtered by pathspec **using `git log`** as follows:

```bash
git log --format="%gd: %gs" -g --first-parent -m refs/stash -- pathspec
```

(Add `-p` to show the patches.)

### Explanation

The `git stash` command [*was* a shell script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8104ec994ea3849a968b4667d072fedd1e688642/git-stash.sh), which made it unusually readable for Git source code.  It appears to not be one any more and the bug may get or be fixed since the link above, which goes to Git version 2.21.0.

The `list_stash` code is at [lines 402-405](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8104ec994ea3849a968b4667d072fedd1e688642/git-stash.sh#L402-L405) and essentially consist of running:

```bash
git log --format="%gd: %gs" -g --first-parent -m "$@" $ref_stash --
```

where `$ref_stash` is `refs/stash` by default.  Note that `$ref_stash` comes *after* `"$@"`.  It should be fancier: since you supplied `--`, it should put your pre-`--` arguments before the `--` and your post-`--` arguments afterward (and drop your `--`), and hence run:

```bash
git log --format="%gd: %gs" -g --first-parent -m refs/stash -- doc
```

which would do what you want.  Instead, it winds up running:

```bash
git log --format="%gd: %gs" -g --first-parent -m -- doc -- refs/stash --
```

which means that `git log` looks at the `HEAD` reflog instead of the `refs/stash` reflog.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1feeaaf26bff51996f9f96c6dc41ca0f95ab5fc4#diff-86621976093d147f898fcd0a43109a81R121-R122) doesn't help me, does it? It's just a shortcut to `git stash show stash@{23}`?

Comment: @Michael: The description of that fix doesn't sound promising, but I'd have to either try it, or look at the code—it's possible that the fix is more extensive than the description.

Comment: For future reference, [the actual commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63b50c8ffe7133d2ec7d243dd9240c14ddfe8a26) also doesn't sound helpful, and the tests suggest it's indeed a shortcut for `git stash show 23` to `git stash show stash@{23}`.